# Display menu when you scroll up but not scroll down

Tags: html, css

Goal:
When you scroll down, the menu page should not display.
However, when you scroll up the page should display.

Problem:
It does go so well to create it. How do I solve it?

Jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/bemefejayu/edit?html,css,js,output

Thank you!

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="top-content" class="palette-1">
              <div id="testtest">
                <img src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/1f/1fa1c2a2ea0d69a85215d878f3a0652a.jpeg" width="100px" height="45px" />
              </div>
              <ul id="iconmenu" class="nav-menu">
                <li class="title">Coffee</li>
                <li class="title">Tea</li>
                <li class="title">Milk</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="palette-2">
                content
                <br />
                              content
                <br />
                              content
                      <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                       <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                        <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                 <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                             <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="palette-4">
                footer
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
body {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin: 0;
}

.palette-1 {
    background-color: #83B2FF;
}

.palette-2 {
    background-color: #8BF18B;
}

.palette-4 { 
    background-color: #FF8650;
}

.palette-5 { 
    background-color: #FF555E;
}

#content {
    grid-area: content;
}

#footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "left-header header right-header"
      "left-content content right-content"
      "left-footer footer right-footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1000px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;    
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }  
  
  #top-content {
    /*    */

    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  #content {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }  
  
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }

  ul.nav-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;

  }

  ul.nav-menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }  
}            


@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {

  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "content"
      "footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }    
  
  #top-content {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    border-top: 3px solid #425c62;
  }
  
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }

  ul.nav-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;

  }

  ul.nav-menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }  
  
  #content {

  }
  
}
```

---

window.onscroll = function() { scrollFunction() };

```
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "-50px";

    
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "0";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<script>
      window.onscroll = function () {
        scrollFunction();
      };

      // get initial pageYOffset value
      let originOffset = window.pageYOffset;

      function scrollFunction() {
        // current pageYOffset value
        const curOffset = window.pageYOffset;
        if (curOffset - originOffset > 0) {
          // down
          document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          // up
          document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'block';
        }
        // change originOffset value every time
        originOffset = window.pageYOffset;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: The code don't work. https://jsbin.com/nuyasukama/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: That's beause the scroll bar is scrolled inside the child element, not in the document. `window.pageYOffset` will always be 0.
If there is not parant of the `container` element in your html, it will work. My english is not very good, hope you understand what i am  saying.